# How to prevent concurrency issues when double clicking form

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have been researching this today, it can often happen that a form is submitted twice if we don't put some safeguards in place. I found this issue on github:

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/23416

```cs
<button disabled="@_busy" Value="do-stuff" />
code{
private bool _busy = false;

public async Task Handler()
{
    if(_busy) return;
    _busy = true;
   try
   {
       // do your thing
   }
   finally
   {
       _busy = false;
   }
}
}
```

The above comment is a solution and comment next to it says:

> You can encapsulate this behavior in a component to avoid having to repeat it every time.

How would I do that? If I have some forms (using Radzen currently) and there is a submit button pointing to `OnSubmit()` method - how could I introduce a component that I put on the component that has form, to avoid having to introduce this pattern every time in every form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea of how such a component could look like.

`MyForm.razor`:

```cs
<EditForm Model="Model" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit">
    @ChildContent?.Invoke(context)
    <button disabled="@_busy">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private bool _busy;

    [Parameter]
    public object? Model { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<EditContext> OnValidSubmit { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment<EditContext>? ChildContent { get; set; }

    private async Task HandleValidSubmit(EditContext editContext)
    {
        if (_busy) return;

        _busy = true;

        try
        {
            await OnValidSubmit.InvokeAsync(editContext);
        }
        finally
        {
            _busy = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
<MyForm Model="_customer" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit">
    <InputText @bind-Value="_customer.FirstName" />
    <InputText @bind-Value="_customer.LastName" />
</MyForm>

@code {
    private Customer _customer = new Customer();

    private async Task HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        // do your thing
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public string? FirstName { get; set; }
        public string? LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

https://blazorfiddle.com/s/gc9w1uvp

Comment: Thanks for this. I will try to implement this with RadzenTemplateForm as it doesn't have this out of the box it seems.

Answer (score 1):

There is a clever way of fixing this issue by utlizing `Detail` property of `MouseEventArgs` which is described as being `A count of consecutive clicks that happened in a short amount of time, incremented by one`, but you need to use a button directly and submit form inside an event handler:

```
<EditForm ... Context="_editContext" OnValidSubmit="EditForm_ValidSubmit">
    <button ... type="submit" @onclick="@Button_ClickAsync" ...></button>
</EditForm>
```

```
protected void Button_ClickAsync(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button != 0 || e.Detail > 1)
        return;

    _editContext.Validate(); // this should submit form according to the documentation
}
```

In general it is a good idea to abstract away this functionality and provide it globally by having a custom button component that invokes your own custom EventCallback `OnClick` (mine is here: https://github.com/rvnlord/CommonLib/blob/master/CommonLib/CommonLib/Source/Common/Utils/UtilClasses/MyEventHandler.cs):

```
[Parameter]
public MyAsyncEventHandler<MyButtonBase, MouseEventArgs> OnClick { get; set; }

protected async Task Button_ClickAsync(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button != 0 || e.Detail > 1)
        return;

    await OnClick.InvokeAsync(this, e).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

```
<MyButton OnClick="BtnTest_ClickAsync">
```

```
protected async Task BtnTest_ClickAsync(MyButtonBase sender, MouseEventArgs e, CancellationToken token)
{
    ...
}
```